# Xamarin.Forms.WebView for UWP - raise navigating event

Tags: xamarin, webview, uwp

I have problem with Xamarin.Forms.WebView and raising an navigating event. For android everything is ok, but for Windows 10 (UWP) the navigation event doesn't work.

```
WebView _webView = new WebView()
{
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
};
_webView.Navigating += WebBrowserNavigating;

private void WebBrowserNavigating(object sender, WebNavigatingEventArgs e)
{
    //...
}
Event "WebBrowserNavigating" is not raising.
```

What I have to do to handle redirects from one website to another in WebView for UWP? Have I use another component? Like Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView? But I need universal component for 3 platforms (Android, UWP, IOS).

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: I can not reproduce your issue, I have made a [demo](https://github.com/mikexxma/XamarinWebView_Demo) for you. Could your please try it?

Comment: Thanks! But the problem is when I used HtmlWebViewSource in webView.Source instead of WebViewSource

Comment: eh~~ I do not understand, can you show the webview.source ?

Comment: When I use HtmlWebViewSource navigating event is not raising:

 `string _htmlSource = "<html>...</html>";
 WebView _webView = new WebView();
 _webView.Source = new HtmlWebViewSource()
 {
  Html = _htmlSource
 };` 
 
For UrlWebViewSource everything is ok:

 `WebView _webView = new WebView();
 _webView.Source = new UrlWebViewSource()
 {
  Url = "https://developer.xamarin.com/"
 };`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved my issue myself. The problem was related to links "a" in html source. Xamarin automatically changed value for "target" attribute from "_self" to "_blank".

When I manually had removed target attribute from links, navigating event raised.